# BitSight discovered Azure staging instance

Tags: azure

We had a company run BitSight against us.

They found a website with an expired certificate and only supplied us with an IP address.

We looked into Azure and found that it was a staging instance of a Cloud Service.

We didn't link back to that URL anywhere. We also didn't expose the IP to anyone, and it was able to detect the site even after the IP changed.

Staging urls are https://{GUID}.cloudapp.net , so you can't really guess that.

How is this even possible without them having some inside knowledge of Azure or some kind of exploit?

Comment: `We had a company run BitSight against us.` - Do you mean that you hired a company to perform this testing? If so, wouldn't it be easier to ask them to explain this to you?

Comment: No we did not. From my understanding any company can pay BitSight to scan your services. So one of our partners hired BitSight to scan services they use, including us. In that scan it said some ip address using our certificate was using an expired certificate. It didn't go into any more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the instance has a wildcard certificate installed, and the instance uses that certificate for all connections to the server.

Then it is trivial to check certificates with a simple scanner that sends requests to port 443 on the server.

If you want to protect against this, you need to install a certificate with this exact domain name in the certificate, and configure another certificate as the default one.